# CakePHP 3 - Simplest way to only allow saving of specific fields on entity

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In Cake 2 you could save a model and specify which fields you wanted to restrict the save to.

Is there a built-in way to do this simply in Cake 3? For example, if the request data is being put straight into a new entity which is then saved, how can I tell the method to only save the fields I allow?

**Simplified Example**

```
// User makes a request; their POST data goes directly into the entity
$customer = $this->Customers->newEntity($this->request->data);
$this->Customers->save($customer);
```

The obvious danger here is that I can set any properties I like on that customer entity, via the request. In reality, I only want to allowing saving of a couple of specific fields.

Comment: To shed some light on your question, do you mind giving us a sample of what you have already tried? Why do you need to be able to save only specific fields vs the entire entity. I am used to doctrine, I am not sure if the saving method is different.

Comment: @AndrewRayner Updated the question. Because the request data from the user is going directly into saving an entity, I want to protect which fields they are allowed to save via this method. Of course I can write some code to check and only save those fields, but in Cake 2 there was a simple way of doing it when saving.

Comment: In that case, the best thing to do is validate the users post results before it is passed to the controller action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what mass assignment protection is there for, in the form of the `$_accessible` entity property

```
class Customer extends Entity
{
    // allow only `first_name` and `last_name` to be mass assigned
    protected $_accessible = [
        'first_name' => true,
        'last_name' => true
    ];
}
```

and the `fieldList` and `accessibleFields` options for `Table::newEntity/newEntities/patchEntity/patchEntities()`

```
// allow only `first_name` and `last_name` to be mass assigned,
// ignoring the entity accessible defaults
$customer = $this->Customers->newEntity($this->request->data(), [
    'fieldList' => [
        'first_name',
        'last_name'
    ]
]);
```

The `accessibleFields` option will change the accessibility of the specified fields only. Also it will actually modify the entity, ie unlike `fieldList`, which the marshaller will simply use as the whitelist instead of the entity defaults, `accessibleFields` will change the values of the entities `$_accessible` property!

See

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Mass Assignment](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Changing Accessible Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#changing-accessible-fields)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::newEntity()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_newEntity)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_patchEntity)**

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of protecting you against this problem. The first one is by setting the default columns that can be safely set from a request using the [Mass Assignment](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#entities-mass-assignment) feature in the entities.

The _accessible property allows you to provide a map of properties and whether or not they can be mass-assigned. The values true and false indicate whether a field can or cannot be mass-assigned:

> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#entities-mass-assignment

```
    namespace App\Model\Entity;

    use Cake\ORM\Entity;

    class Article extends Entity
    {
        protected $_accessible = [
       'title' => true,
        'body' => true,
         '*' => false,
    ];
   }
```

The second way is by using the fieldList option when creating or merging data into an entity:

```
        // Contains ['user_id' => 100, 'title' => 'Hacked!'];
          $data = $this->request->data;

        // Only allow title to be changed
          $entity = $this->patchEntity($entity, $data, [
                  'fieldList' => ['title']
                 ]);
           $this->save($entity);
```

You can also control which properties can be assigned for associations:

```
            // Only allow changing the title and tags
           // and the tag name is the only column that can be set
              $entity = $this->patchEntity($entity, $data, [
                       'fieldList' => ['title', 'tags'],
                       'associated' => ['Tags' => ['fieldList' => ['name']]]
                       ]);
              $this->save($entity);
```

Using this feature is handy when you have many different functions your users can access and you want to let your users edit different data based on their privileges.

The fieldList options is also accepted by the newEntity(), newEntities() and patchEntities() methods.

> For more :http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html